# Sign a file with a X509Certificate2 and private key

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I would like to sign a file with a certificate. I wrote the following code but I get a "File content error" and also I always asked the private key.
What did I do wrong? How can I send the private key?
Thank you all.

```
        string cSerial = "0C4744041F40B761322124EB691C5F32";
        //Find my certificate with serial    
        X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;

        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in my.Certificates)
        {
            if (cert.SerialNumber.Trim() == cSerial)
            { csp = (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey; }
        }
        //Here i have the certificate, it's ok.
        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed sha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed();
        UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        //////////byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes("test.xml");
        byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("test.xml")
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
        byte[] aa = csp.SignHash(hash, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));
        File.WriteAllBytes("text.p7m", aa);

        my.Close();
```

Comment: UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes does not read a file. It simply encodes the bytes in the string "text.xml" to a byte array.

Comment: @Kevin, i edit my source but the result not change.......thanks.

Comment: Use the debugger and find out which line is producing the error.

Comment: I solved it by just using BouncyCastle.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this without Bouncy Castle, just using .NET

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Make attached signature.
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] SignAttached(X509Certificate2 certificate, byte[] dataToSign)
    {
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(dataToSign);
        SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, false);
        CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(certificate);
        cms.ComputeSignature(signer, false);
        return cms.Encode();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Make detached signature.
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] SignDetached(X509Certificate2 certificate, byte[] dataToSign)
    {
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(dataToSign);
        SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);
        CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(certificate);
        cms.ComputeSignature(signer, false);
        return cms.Encode();
    }
```

Comment: How to verify the signature in attached and detached scenario ?